# Get part of the string between 2 different strings

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, substring

I'm using *SQL-Server 2008 R2*.

First of all, I want to tell you that's I know that store strings like this is super bad practice, but as I'm SQL developer I don't have an ability to change it, the software of third-party generating output and inserting to the database like this.

---

**Explanation**

Sample value looks like:

```
Name: 'Document No. 996'
Unique No: 'A 54 x. 488sCHU'
No 2: 'RF123456789'
String 'This is dynamic text' value 'test' wrong data
Values 'ETC1 ETC2'.
```

Note: this is 1 value (1 column, 1 row)

As you see above, the structure is like: After word `Name` is added `:` then in single quotes, then some document no, after it line break and so on.

---

**What I need (desired results)**

I need to extract from that string this part: `String 'This is dynamic text'`.

This part always starts with word `String`, after it will be 1 space and in single quotes will be some text.

So it looks like I have look between 2 chars, first would be `String '` and second `'`.

I have to use maybe `SUBSTRING` and `CHARINDEX`, but in anyway I can't achieve it.

---

**What I've tried**

There is sample data and what I've tried, just without success:

```
DECLARE @c varchar(100)
SET     @c = 'Name: ''Document No. 996''
Unique No: ''A 54 x. 488sCHU''
No 2: ''RF123456789''
String ''This is dynamic text'' value ''test'' wrong data
Values ''ETC1 ETC2''.'


SELECT SUBSTRING(STUFF(@c, 1, CHARINDEX('String ''',@c), ''), 0, CHARINDEX('''', STUFF(@c, 1, CHARINDEX('String ''',@c), '')))
```

Comment: @YogeshSharma desired result is in `What I need` section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use it

```
DECLARE @c varchar(1000)
SET     @c = 'Name: ''Document No. 996''
Unique No: ''A 54 x. 488sCHU''
No 2: ''RF123456789''
String ''This is dynamic text'' value ''test'' wrong data
Values ''ETC1 ETC2''.'


SELECT SUBSTRING( @c, CHARINDEX('String ''',@c) , CHARINDEX('''', @c, CHARINDEX('String ''',@c)+8  ) - CHARINDEX('String ''',@c)+1)
```

Result:

```
String 'This is dynamic text'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @c varchar(255) --100 will truncate your string
SET     @c = 'Name: ''Document No. 996''
Unique No: ''A 54 x. 488sCHU''
No 2: ''RF123456789''
String ''This is dynamic text'' value ''test'' wrong data
Values ''ETC1 ETC2''.'
```

Here is solution split in two parts for better understanding. First part is to find substring that starts with `String` keyword and goes until the end of the original string. We store it @c1, to reuse it twice. Second part is finding next `'` but only in @c1 and cutting everything right from it.

```
DECLARE @c1 Varchar(255)
SELECT @c1 =  SUBSTRING(@c, CHARINDEX('String ''',@c) + 8, 255)  
--This is dynamic text' value 'test' wrong data  Values 'ETC1 ETC2'.

SELECT LEFT(@c1, CHARINDEX('''',@c1) - 1)
--This is dynamic text
```

All put together - in single query:

```
SELECT LEFT(SUBSTRING(@c, CHARINDEX('String ''',@c) + 8, 255), CHARINDEX('''',SUBSTRING(@c, CHARINDEX('String ''',@c) + 8, 255)) - 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not Sure but you are looking something as below :

```
DECLARE @DATA NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @DATA = 'Name: ''Document No. 996''
Unique No: ''A 54 x. 488sCHU''
No 2: ''RF123456789''
String ''This is dynamic text'' value ''test'' wrong data
Values ''ETC1 ETC2''.';

SELECT SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING(@DATA, CHARINDEX('String', @DATA), CHARINDEX('Values', @DATA)-CHARINDEX('String', @DATA)), 1, CHARINDEX('''', SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING(@DATA, CHARINDEX('String', @DATA), CHARINDEX('Values', @DATA)-CHARINDEX('String', @DATA)), CHARINDEX('''', SUBSTRING(@DATA, CHARINDEX('String', @DATA), CHARINDEX('Values', @DATA)-CHARINDEX('String', @DATA)))+1, LEN(SUBSTRING(@DATA, CHARINDEX('String', @DATA), CHARINDEX('Values', @DATA)-CHARINDEX('String', @DATA)))))+CHARINDEX('''', SUBSTRING(@DATA, CHARINDEX('String', @DATA), CHARINDEX('Values', @DATA)-CHARINDEX('String', @DATA))));
```

**Result :**

```
String 'This is dynamic text'
```